# Suggestions for creating a more complex tiered content type

Tags: entities, nodes

I need to create a content type where users will be able to create a tiered structure. This will be generated into a PDF and displayed using the Drupal templating system as well.  I will need some sort of multi-valued field so that the user can add as many items as they like. I need the content structure to look like this:

- Content Title
- Custom Category Title

  - Custom item
  - Custom item Subheading

    - Custom subitem 1
    - Custom subitem 2
- Another Custom item

  etc...

I'm considering [Multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) (We've used field collection before and had issues with translation)

Or possibly a [Custom Field type](https://www.drupal.org/node/2620964)

If I used multifield, one option might be to have the user specify these things for each item ( Is it a subitem parent?, Is it a subitem?, If it is, what is it's parent?)

This is Drupal 7 and we'll be using Entity translation to handle translating this content type for all of our domains.

Comment: Paragraphs like Stephanos mentioned or have a look at the field collection module.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely suggest using [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs), it's a killer module for multi-valued, arbitrary ordered fields inside content types.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion Stefanos. I did try the paragraphs module and it looked very promising...until I tried to use it with Entity Translation, then everything went to hell in a handbasket. I downloaded a stock version of Drupal and Paragraphs to confirm this was the issue.

I just wanted to leave this for others who stumble upon this. While paragraph looks like a great module, it doesn't meet my requirements for Entity Translation. Also it looks like they're mostly focused on the d8 version, so it looks like the [Entity Translation Issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2452675) may not be addressed for a bit.

I create two versions for the users to test one using the Multifield module, which worked nice with ET, but in contrast to field collection can't do multi-valued fields inside of itself.

The second version users actually liked better which was just a taxonomy vocab, term reference, and entity reference. So, no new modules and they were able to simplify the structure a bit.